# How to display events from start to end date in a calendar view in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Hello Dev's i need your help.

When displaying events in a calendar view, it is important to show the events from their start to end date. However, in JavaScript, it can be tricky to loop through the dates in between the start and end date of an event.

Can u help how to display events from start to end date in a calendar view in JavaScript.

**here is the code.**

[CODE-SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/embed/summer-forest-nfnkbu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I try to make output Of Calendar needs to look like this.
[image]